# Getting client is closed on TypeScript class that is used to access Redis

Tags: typescript, redis

My class

```
import * as redis from 'redis';

export class RedisClient {
    private client: any

    constructor() {
        this.client = redis.createClient()
    }

    public async set(key: string, value: any): Promise<void> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.client.set(key, value, (err: any) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve();
                }
            });
        });
    }

    public async get(key: string): Promise<string> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.client.get(key, (err: any, value: string | PromiseLike<string>) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(value);
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

I know I need to add `this.client.connect()` and I was hoping I could add it to constructor but that doesn't work. I get client is closed. It does work if I add `this.client.connect` within the set method but is the approach considered good if we are connecting to Redis every single time before calling set/get?

Is there a better approach to this

---

Update:
Taking answer into suggestion, created with Singleton pattern. Added the following in RedisClient

```
let cached: Promise<RedisClient>;
static instance(): Promise<RedisClient> {
    if (!cached) cached = RedisClient.create();
    return cached;
}
```

In caller class

```
constructor() {
    this.redisClient = RedisClient.instance();
}
public async handle(event: DynamoDBStreamEvent): Promise<void> {
    const client = await this.redisClient;
    ....
}
```

This works but I am not too familiar with typescript. Is this considered a good pattern. My intention is that RedisClient is only instantiated once so we are not always re-connecting to Redis with every operation

Answer (score 1):

This is just a limitation of JavaScript and thus TypeScript. The `.connect` function is `async` and so you can't put it in the constructor. What's happening is that the resolution of the call to `.connect` is not happening before the rest of your code runs. You need to wait for `.connect` to resolve before you can use the Redis client.

If I find myself writing this sort of class, I usually add a static method that calls `.createClient` and `.connect` together and then use that method instead of `new`. There's a lot of ways to skin this cat, but here's one:

```js
import { createClient } from 'redis'

type RedisConnection = ReturnType<typeof createClient>

export class RedisClient {

  private connection: RedisConnection

  constructor(connection: RedisClientConnection) {
    this.connection = connection
  }

  async static create() {
    const connection = redis.createClient()
    connection.on('error', (err) => console.log('Redis Client Error', err))
    await connection.connect()

    return new RedisClient(connection)
  }

  public async set(key: string, value: any): Promise<void> {
    return this.connection.set(key, value)
  }

  public async get(key: string): Promise<string> {
    return this.connection.get(key)
  }
}
```

Note a few things here:

1. I renamed `client` to `connection` since you are creating a class called `RedisClient` as I thought it would be confusing to have two things called "Client".
2. I added some error handling so you know what's going on when stuff breaks. Optional, but recommended. And you might want to do something a bit more robust.
3. I got rid of the pesky `any` for you using `ReturnType`! ;)
4. I removed all the callback/promise logic. Node Redis 4.x supports promises now so there's no need for it.

You might even take this a step further and use a Singleton pattern here as Redis rarely needs more than one connection for a Node.js application.

Comment: I updated original question, taking your suggestions into account

Answer (score 0):

What i would do in your situation is the wrap the redis connection in a IIF and assign the result to the client property on the class

```
import * as redis from 'redis';

export class RedisClient {
private client: any

constructor() {
   (async()=>{
    this.client = redis.createClient();
    await this.client.connect()
   })()
}

public async set(key: string, value: any): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.client.set(key, value, (err: any) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve();
            }
        });
    });
}

public async get(key: string): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.client.get(key, (err: any, value: string | PromiseLike<string>) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(value);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

}